# Windows Server store apps not working

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am using Windows Server and create a new admin user.

Now when I run it's open but goes hide after 2-3 seconds. When I check the left-side top then it's still exist.

In Event Viewer I got this error:

> App winstore_cw5n1h2txyewy!Windows.Store did not launch within its
>   allotted time.
>
> Activation of app winstore_cw5n1h2txyewy!Windows.Store failed with
>   error: The system cannot find the file specified. See the
>   Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

Comment: Try to see ["unable to run any Metro app once Win8 machine is joined to domain and group policy is processed"](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/acc45e6e-86fe-4928-9f33-429ce8bebc8f)

Comment: Having the same issue. I had a broken nvRAID pair (my mobo fried) which I split(used linux to mount). I copied the files to another drive and back after partitioning the drives without RAID. Maybe it is about some broken symlinks?

Comment: Mine is not windows server though.

Answer (score 1):

A list of things that might help with App Store problems ([source](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f320/windows-8-metro-apps-do-not-work-688067.html)) :

1. Make sure your computer is fully patched including optional updates
2. Make sure UAC is turned on
3. If you are using skydrive, you may need to have your Microsoft profile filled out completely or apps stop working after installing skydrive
4. check DCOM settings
   a. go to the start screen (from the desktop click the windows start key)
   b. type `comexp.msc`
   c. click Component Services, click Computers, and then click My Computer
   d. right-click My Computer, click Properties
   e. click Default Properties tab. Make sure Enable Distributed COM on this computer is checked.
   f. click COM Security tab. Click Edit Limits under Access Permissions. Make sure All Application Packages has Local Access Checked
   g. on the COM Security tab click Edit Limits under the Launch and Activation Permissions section. Make sure All Application Packages has Local Launch and Local Activation permissions.
5. try running the Apps Troubleshooter. You should be able to find it in your c:\ folder. It is called `AppsDiagnostic.diagcab`.
6. Check the "All Application Packages" permissions
7. Clear the store cache
   a. Press <kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> 
   b. Type `wsreset.exe` and click OK
8. Fix Proxy issues, as a windows internal HTTP service might not be using the proxy settings defined in IE. Running the following command changes the service to use the IE proxy settings. Open a command prompt with 'Run as Administrator' and type:
   `netsh`
   `winhttp`
   `import proxy source=ie`
9. Disable Proxy connection if enabled (use this only if your network setup does not require a proxy)
   a. press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and type ‘Internet Options’ and press enter.
   b. click on 'Connections' tab.
   c. click on 'LAN settings'.
   d. uncheck 'Use a proxy server for your LAN'.
   e. under ‘Automatic Configuration’ select 'Automatically detect settings'.
   f. click on ‘Ok’ and click on ‘Apply’ and ‘Ok’ again.
10. Enable HyperV (probably doesn't apply here)
11. Uninstall your antivirus if not from Microsoft.
12. Ensure the date/time and time zone are correct.
13. Try another administrator user account.
14. Ensure you're using a Windows Live account.
15. [sfc /scannow](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3047-sfc-scannow-command-run-windows-8-a.html).
16. [Turn off Internet sharing](http://lekhak.org/home/en/content/solution-windows-8-metro-apps-not-working).
17. If the problem is new, rollback your system to a system restore point dating from before the problem started
18. [Refresh your Windows 8 system from a Recovery Drive](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/refresh-your-windows-8-system-from-a-recovery-drive/7384)
    while keeping all of your data, settings, and apps.
19. If you have upgraded from Windows 7, do a clean install of Windows 8.

Comment: 5th does not exist, however I have downloaded something from MS that is supposed to fix this problem but it does not. It always finds some errors, says it has fixed them but it finds them again when I run it.
8th does not work either. Saying 'cannot find ms-windows-store:PurgeCaches'. I don't know how to do 6th and 11th.

Comment: 5 : see [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/20291-windows-store-apps-troubleshooter-fix-apps-windows-8-a.html). 6 : see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/432859/metro-apps-crash-on-startup-driver-or-permissions-issue.) 8 : What doesn't work? New: 12. Uninstall your antivirus if not from Microsoft.

Comment: 8: wsreset.exe does not work, says 'cannot find ms-windows-store:PurgeCaches'.

Comment: I tried to refresh, it also failed. When I got to desktop it said 'there was a problem refreshing your pc, check for solutions'. I clicked 'check for solutions', it said checking for a while then it disappeared and nothing happened.

Comment: Your Windows is sick. New - **13:** Ensure the date/time and time zone are correct. **14:** Try another administrator user account. **15:** Ensure you're using a Windows Live account. **16:** [sfc /scannow](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3047-sfc-scannow-command-run-windows-8-a.html). **17:** [Turn off Internet sharing](http://lekhak.org/home/en/content/solution-windows-8-metro-apps-not-working). **18:** If you have upgraded from Windows 7, do a clean install of Windows 8 (I'm afraid we are fast approaching this one).

Comment: See also #18 I've added to my answer above.

Comment: I have tried everything, nothing worked. I booted from an installation disc and tried to do repair. It also failed. I decided I needed to 'Refresh the PC' in case I have to use my PC for work in the future and it fails. It solved the Store problem for me.

Comment: Yes, I have reordered my points above so that refresh is one before the last possible remedy. Windows 8 seems pretty fragile, so better keep it patched, especially when 8.1 comes along.

Answer (score 0):

In my case only updating NVidia Graphics Driver helped to resolve issue with all Windows Store Apps not working on Windows 10.
I had this in Application Event Logs:

```
 because of an issue with Windows binary \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\nvspcap64.dll. This could be because the binary is unsigned, contains an untrusted signature, or has been corrupted or tampered with. Refresh your PC to fix this issue.
```

Comment: Author is using Windows Server 2012.  What does your answer have to do with the author's problem?

Comment: I added to existing answer with multiple steps and I see they refer to Windows 7 and 8.I see that he still didn’t find the root cause and wanted to let him know what helped me even though it was Windows 10 Pro. I just followed similar instructions from Microsof with many steps, but all for nothing. When I google I would be happy to stumble upon somebody having same issue because of the driver.
First signal for me was that in Safe Mode with networking Windows Store applications started working.

Comment: Windows Store doesn’t exist on Windows 7.  Your solution isn’t applicable to the author