# Windows 8 Metro Apps won't load

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

How do I get my Windows 8 Metro apps to load? The tiles update, but when I click on them, they spin around and show the solid splash screen, then disappear. Only the Store app opens. I've tried:

1. Setting user access control to one notch below the top.
2. "Refresh My PC" (Don't do this - waste of time. Deletes all your desktop apps too.)
3. Turned off real time scan of my McAfee anti virus.
4. Went into Store app and updated apps.
5. Ran `sfc /scannow`
6. Ran the App Troubleshooter.

This is a new computer. I've already ran Windows update. They worked the first few days.

Here is a list of some event log errors: http://pastie.org/6415709

Comment: which apps aren't working, as the windows store works it seems to be specific apps not all apps in general.

Comment: All apps. News. Weather. Finance. People. Mails... etc. Kindle. Skype.

Comment: It sounds like your logged into the default `Administrator` account built into Windows.

Comment: I'm logged in as 'Chloe'. I do have Administrator rights, and I seem to be the only account besides Guest, which is off.

Comment: There was a similar question from somebody in the past with a problem like this, they had installed a Windows 8 printer application, and they discovered this program was the reason this behavior surfaced.  Sadly the only solution that worked for them was to do a fresh installation of Windows 8.

Comment: most of the apps you mention require an internet connection - I'm assuming there is no issue with your connection or firewall?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/432859/metro-apps-crash-on-startup-driver-or-permissions-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run the App Troubleshooter:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271185

Also make sure that the registry/folder permissions are not changed:

**Win8: App: Modern: Apps fail to start if default registry or file permissions modified**
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2798317/en-us

Comment: Ok I believe I ran that too, because when I tried it just now, it downloaded AppsDiagnostics(1).diagcab. Here is the log of what it did: http://pastie.org/6415092. Will report back after reboot.

Comment: No that did not work...

Comment: I looked at the KB article, but did not see that error. Instead, I saw this error: http://pastie.org/6415279

Comment: In the KB article, I checked permissions, and only this was missing, which I added "Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER - Special Permissions (List folder / read data, Create Folders /Append Data)". Also, there was no HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\DRIVERS. The apps still won't load.

Comment: Run process Monitor while trying to start an app. Now look into the result column for errors.

Comment: Do you mean Resource Monitor?

Comment: What is Monitor? Where do I find it?

Comment: no, ProcessMonitor from sysinternals: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Wow, I don't even know what process to look for. There were half a million events in half a minute. Which process do I filter for?

Comment: I think I found it. Here is a text log of all the events for wwahost.exe that where Result is not SUCCESS when I tried to launch the News app: http://pastebin.com/0sMkkAex. Here is the binary PML file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0fbzzag84xtkee/Logfile.PML.

Comment: I added ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES to ‪C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Local\Packages with Modify permissions (which selects everything except Full Control), and the apps work now.

Comment: nice to hear that you fixed it :)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, the apps opened for a moment then minimized and did not open.

I found that this command from [MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/notime/archive/2013/10/18/fix-store-app-in-windows-8-1.aspx),  fixes the issue for each app. Just Change the name of the app you are trying to fix and done.

> 1. Open a elevated Command Prompt.
> 2. Execute the following command:
>
> powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage
>   -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot******\AppxManifest.XML

Example: To solve problem with **WinStore** App:

> powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.XML

To solve problem with **Camera** App:

> powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\camera\AppxManifest.xml

To solve problem with **FileManager** App:

> powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\FileManager\AppxManifest.xml

To solve problem with **ImmersiveControlPanel** App:

> powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\ImmersiveControlPanel\AppxManifest.xml

---

Another fix is from [Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c4147bcc-a430-43fe-b4e9-f999552568da/81-store-apps-wont-load?forum=w8itprogeneral):

The following finally fixed all issues for me (Store and all apps broken):

A.) Fixing the app store:
Run from admin command prompt:

> Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.xml

B.) Fixing all modern apps:
Run from admin PowerShell:

> ((Get-ChildItem "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\InboxApplications") | Get-ItemProperty).Path | Add-AppxPackage -Register -DisableDevelopmentMode

C.) Fixing 3rd party apps:

Delete the regkey:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore[UserSID]

You can find your SID by going to an elevated command prompt and typing

> wmic useraccount get name,sid

Comment: This fixed my problems I was seeing on the Windows 10 Technical Preview. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue after a Steam game installed .Net Framework. My only solution was to do the factory reset in Windows 8 -> Charm bar -> Settings - Change PC Settings -> General it's the option up from the last saying "Remove everything and re-install Windows"

Unfortunately I never found out which .Net update messed it up.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and found that uninstalling and reinstalling the apps fixed it - except for a couple of apps that I didn't use much. You can delete all the apps that aren't working properly, then go into the Store and select the 'Your Apps' option. It will list all the apps you had installed, so you can select them all and reinstall them all with one click.

It's worth trying this before resetting or reinstalling Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything posted to fix this problem 
The last thing I did was try:
`ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` need the following permissions to execute properly:

Read & execute, List folder contents and Read in the following locations
C:\Windows
C:\Program Files (x86)
C:\Program Files
List folder and read data, Create Folders and Append Data
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER
Read
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM`
`HKEY_USERS`

My `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` was wrong
Fixed it and Modern Apps run OK

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I decided to move my users and appdata folders to my d: drive.

Apparently "modern ui" (aka Metro) simply won't work if you do this:

http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2787623